# How should I structure an MVC 4 + WebApi + Linq-to-Sql solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api

I understand that stackoverflow uses Linq to SQL.  I decided that since stackoverflow uses linq to sql (and in my opinion works well in a high traffic site), that I would continue using it in my MVC 4 application.

What I have thus far in my solution is an MVC 4 internet project, an web api project, model class library, used to override some of the mapping in linq to sql, and then my linq to sql library project.

I noticed when I added a web api project to the solution, the api project also had views, controllers etc. as the regular mvc 4 project.

Does the web api project provide the same abilities for views etc, as MVC 4 web project?
What would you recommend for project settings...

1. Eliminate the mvc 4 internet project and just use the web api.
2. Eliminate the web api and use a repository?
3. Use both the mvc 4 internet project and the web api?
   Or ?????  and why?

I am moving an asp.net web forms application over to mvc. Since stackoverflow uses linq to sql I decided re-use my linq to sql library instead of creating linq to entities.

All data access and manipulation is done using linq to sql, so it's a lot easier for me to just move the queries over to the web api.

I want to re-use as much code as possible and will be using Telerik's Kendo UI for MVC.

The application will need to work both on-line and offline, so I thought the api would be good.

But after noticing that the api contains the same object types as the mvc internet project, I didn't see why I would use both the internet and api mvc projects.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Can you update your question with your goal / trouble you are facing ?

Comment: `WWSOD` questions should be posted on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Actually, Stack Overflow has replaced most of the linq-to-sql queries with raw SQL run through [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)... but they were linq-to-sql for a long time and were able to handle quite a lot of traffic with it.

Comment: I just checked out Dapper... Interesting. As time goes on I will probably follow the same path.

Comment: @SheriTrager Microsoft stopped supporting linq to sql , use entity framework

Comment: Yes, I know they stopped support it and will probably use Dapper, but for now I want to reuse as much code as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go both ways. If you create a Web API project, it comes with all MVC4 features.  In the controllers folder project, if you right click and say new, you have the option to create a Web API controller or an MVC controller. Since both have different URLs(Web APi will have /api/ in the url by default), you can decide whether to call MVC4 controller or Web API controller.

Comment: Any difference with views?  I will be using the Telerik Kendo UI for MVC.? 
Thanks

Comment: No difference. The views that you see in the Web API project are MVC4 views. Web API is the service layer. it does not have concept of views! I still dont understand why Microsoft decided to give all the MVC4 stuff when we create a new Web API project!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I now know I can remove the internet project and just use the api.  
It seemed like extra work to use both.
Thanks again!

Comment: The reason why Views are available is because services can still return Views (Partial or Entire to a requester) as data.

Comment: Yea, but shouldnt it be optional considering Web API is supposed to be used as a service? And if you are using it only as a service which out puts JSON/XML, we need to delete tons of unwanted MVC4 stuff from the project.

Comment: I think it is a nice choice because it is easier to remove that MVC stuff than bundle it in afterwards if it wasn't included. It adds no weight to your API and automatically gives you a way to present a configuration/management interface bundled right into your API. I never removed the MVC stuff, and always leverage it by adding a pretty management interface for my services.